# Slick Carousel can't insert a second slider without turn a broken grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I'm got some problem implementing Slick within a CSS3 Grid environment. I can't implement more than one slide, without breaking the grid and getting totally broken.

Here's the code that I'm working.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#carousel').slick({
    infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 2,
  dots: true,
  settings: "unslick"
  });
});
```

```css
#main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 10vh auto auto 10vh;
  grid-template-areas: "header nav" "carousel carousel" "content content" "form form";
}

.mainCarousel {
  grid-area: carousel;
  background: gray;
}

.carousel-item {
  max-height: 300px;
}

#carousel img {
  max-height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <article class="mainCarousel">
      <div id="carousel" class="carousel-item">
        <h1>SLIDE 1</h1>
        <h1>SLIDE 2</h1>
        <h3>SLIDE 3</h3>
      </div>

    </article>
```

I would like to insert two or more slides, without problems.

Check the pictures attached.

[Screen 1 without a second slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWbSr.jpg)

[Screen 2 with a second slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub0Vh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This works if you remove `grid-area: carousel;` from `.mainCarousel`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#carousel').slick({
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2
  });
});
```

```css
@import "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css";

#main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 10vh auto auto 10vh;
  grid-template-areas: "header nav" "carousel carousel" "content content" "form form";
}

.mainCarousel {
  /* grid-area: carousel; */
  background: gray;
}

.carousel-item {
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <article class="mainCarousel">

    <div id="carousel" class="carousel-item">
      <div>
        <h1>SLIDE 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>SLIDE 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>SLIDE 3</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </article>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```